# Oracle sql MINUS help: Show faculty that teaches a specific AND not qualified to teach a specific course

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

1st table

```
CREATE TABLE qualified (
    facultyid integer NOT NULL,
    courseid character varying(16) NOT NULL,
    datequalified character varying(16),
    dq2 date,
    CONSTRAINT qualified_pkey PRIMARY KEY (facultyid, courseid)
);

INSERT INTO qualified VALUES (3467, 'ISM 4212', to_date('9/1995', 'MM/YYYY'), date '1995-09-01');
INSERT INTO qualified VALUES (4756, 'ISM 3112', to_date('9/1991', 'MM/YYYY'), date '1991-09-01');
INSERT INTO qualified VALUES (2143, 'ISM 3113', to_date('9/1988', 'MM/YYYY'), date '1988-09-01');
INSERT INTO qualified VALUES (4756, 'ISM 3113', to_date('9/1991', 'MM/YYYY'), date '1991-09-01');
INSERT INTO qualified VALUES (2143, 'ISM 3112', to_date('9/1988', 'MM/YYYY'), date '1988-09-01');
INSERT INTO qualified VALUES (3467, 'ISM 4930', to_date('9/1996', 'MM/YYYY'), date '1996-09-01');
```

2nd table:

```
CREATE TABLE faculty (
    facultyid integer NOT NULL,
    facultyname character varying(25),
    CONSTRAINT faculty_pkey PRIMARY KEY (facultyid)
);

INSERT INTO faculty VALUES (2143, 'Birkin');
INSERT INTO faculty VALUES (3467, 'Berndt');
INSERT INTO faculty VALUES (4756, 'Collins');
```

Query: Is any instructor qualified to teach ISM 4212 and not qualified to teach ISM 4930?

The query i tried:

```
SELECT q.facultyid, facultyname, q.courseid
FROM qualified q, faculty fa
WHERE q.facultyid = fa.facultyid AND courseid = 'ISM 4212'
MINUS
SELECT q.facultyid, facultyname, q.courseid
FROM qualified q, faculty fa
WHERE q.facultyid = fa.facultyid AND courseid = 'ISM 4930';
```

It displays: 3467   Berndt  ISM 4212

Instead of: NOTHING/No Result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the following from the select clause solved the problem:

```
q.courseid
```